# How to copy a path from "recent items" in any MS Office application?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

or "recent places" for that matter

It's not possible to copy the location from the application, so is this list stored somewhere else e.g. registry, file system, xml config file?

The problem is that someone has decided to move a file on the network and I'd like to examine the folder/parent folder but that path name is huge and complex

*To see this open any MS Office application and go to **FILE** then **RECENT***

Answer (score 0):

Check shortcuts created under `%AppData%\Microsoft\Office\Recent`.

Comment: there is nothing in that location that resembles the documents I can see in 'recent'